# Using vyprvpn on kubuntu

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to use kubuntu since qq month I use vyprvpn with windows 10 without problem I would like to do with kubuntu 14.04 Despite using network-manager (under) pptp and others I can not do it How ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried PPTP (and see no reason to - it's [utterly broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security) security-wise), but I have tried OpenVPN and that works just fine.

They have a [fairly detailed tutorial](https://support.goldenfrog.com/hc/en-us/articles/227258228-VyprVPN-OpenVPN-Setup-for-Linux-Ubuntu-) listing the steps required, step by step, including all commands. I suggest you follow that - I have used it for configuring VyprVPN connections a few times, and had no problems with it.

Comment: ok many thangs  i am going to try

Comment: since i try twice following step by step your advise.

Comment: now i thing vyprvpn is installed  but i cannot open it.when i connect few moment after it crahs . it possible something wrong on my configuration ??